# Wasabi S3 Ckeditor connect

Tags: php, ckeditor, ckfinder, wasabi

I want to keep my files in wasabi s3. I am uploading and displaying single images independently.
But I need to upload images via **ckeditor and ckfinder.**

I only changed the config information in the AWS library in Ckfinder and the submission failed.
Which files should I work on as additional settings? Or is there a library I can use?
**I use integration language php**

My conf;

```
$config['backends'][] = [
    'name'         => 'default',
    'adapter'      => 's3',
    'bucket'       => 'mycdn',
    'region'       => 'eu-west-2', 
    'key'          => 'xxxxx',
    'secret'       => 'xxxxx',
    'endpoint'     => 'https://s3.wasabisys.com', 
    'use_path_style_endpoint' => true, 

];
```

Err: (amazonaws.com) where can I change the link?

`Fatal error: Uncaught Aws\S3\Exception\PermanentRedirectException: Encountered a permanent redirect while requesting https://mycdn.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/?list-type=2&prefix=images%2F522117%2F.ckfinder%2Fcache%2Fthumbs%2F.htaccess%2F&max-keys=1&delimiter=%2F. Are you sure you are using the correct region for this bucket? in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\editor\ckfinder\core\connector\php\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\S3\PermanentRedirectMiddleware.php:49`